# A way to invert the binary value of a integer variable

Tags: c#

I have this integer `int nine = 9;` which in binary is `1001`. Is there an easy way to invert it so I can  get `0110` ?

Comment: An **int** 9 in C# is not `1001`.  Hint: it is more than 4 bits.

Comment: Just to give the answer to mbeckish's hint `int 9` is `0000 0000 0000 1001` so if you "invert 9" that will give you `1111 1111 1111 0110`

Comment: @neoistheone Not in the Halloween spirit today?

Comment: @Servy, LOL, I guess not!

Comment: This question would be more interesting if you were asking to invert only bits 0..the most significant bit, for any given int.

Answer (score 49):

```
int notnine = ~nine;
```

If you're worried about only the last byte:

```
int notnine = ~nine & 0x000000FF;
```

And if you're only interested in the last nibble:

```
int notnine = ~nine & 0x0000000F;
```

The [~ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d2bd4x66.aspx) is the bitwise negation, while the mask gives you only the byte/nibble you care about.

If you truly are interested in only the last nibble, the **most** simple is:

```
int notnine = 15 - nine;
```

Works for every nibble. :-)

Comment: Looks like the OP wants the last nibble.

Comment: @mbeckish I've edited the code for that in to the post around the same time you commented.  :-)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you're doing is the same as an XOR. So you could simplify to just `int notnine = nine ^ 0x000000FF`.

Comment: @xr280xr XOR of a value with 1's will effectively negate the value, but your idea will not mask properly. E.g. if the value was 0xdeadbeef, the expected result for the last byte would be 0x00000010, but your answer would give 0x21625110 (I think - doing it all in my head, so I might have messed one up).

Answer (score 17):

There's an operator specifically for it, `~`.

```
nine = ~nine;
```

Comment: Depends if the OP wants 3 or -10 as the result.

Comment: @mbeckish, what do you mean by that specifically?

Comment: @neoistheone - See Scott Chamberlain's comments to the question.

Comment: @neoistheone in the Op's example he only showed inverting the first nibble of the int, mbeckish is saying it depends on if the op wants `0000 0000 0000 0110` or `1111 1111 1111 0110` as a result.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: @neoistheone - I can see why that was confusing.  I meant 6, not 3.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is not completely specified - do you only care about 4 bits, or should the answer adjust to the number of significant bits in the input? If it's the latter then you'll need some sophisticated bit manipulation to mask off the upper bits.

I'll slightly modify a [Bit Twiddling Hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) to create the mask.

```
int mask = num;
mask |= mask >> 1;
mask |= mask >> 2;
mask |= mask >> 4;
mask |= mask >> 8;
mask |= mask >> 16;
int inverse = ~num & mask;
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/pEqwwM

Answer (score 2):

If we consider 9 as an integer like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000001001
```

and you want to have:

```
00000000000000000000000000000110
```

instead of:

```
11111111111111111111111111110110
```

And do care about more than the last nibble (e.g. also want to handle 128903).

Then you can create a mask and apply it:

```
uint value = 9; //or try 1290320
uint mask = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i *= 2)
     mask |= mask >> i;
value = mask & (~value);
```

You could speed this up using a modified version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set, or using the bsf asm instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Use xor with 111111....

```
var inverted = a ^ int.MinValue
```

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers, assuming you mean int.MaxValue.

Comment: Af far as I know, `a ^ int.MaxValue` flips 31 bits, and there's 32 of them in an int. Actually, it's wrong for every int, not just negative ones, I just got confused byt the fact that it is bit 32, the one that tells you the sign of the number, that is wrong. What would be correct, I believe, is `a ^ int.MinValue`.

Comment: you could cast to unsigned integer first

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a mask for the last n bits that you want to flip

```
mask = (1<<n) - 1
```

2) use xor

```
a ^ mask
```

Additionally if you want to flip bits starting from the first 1 in binary representation you can do this

```
n = 0; while ((1<<n) <= a) n++;
```